# List Compherension with sublist

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Suppose I have a list of sublist:

```
lst = [ ['A', 'is', 'from', 'B,', '2', 'm', 'from', 'C', '1.2', 'm', 'from', 'D.'], 
        ['0.3', 'm', 'from', 'D.'] ]
```

and I wanted to organize the letters after the word "from" so I want to have

```
new_lst = [ [B,C,D], [D] ]
```

Comment: Telling us the language would be a start. Showing what you've tried yourself would be useful as well.

Comment: I actually got it working after a few tries :)
PS: (I tagged python in this question + I'm new in this website)
So cut me some slack xp

Answer (score 6):

As you're talking about list comprehensions, you're probably writing in Python.

So I wrote the most awesome comprehension you may find to solve that problem.

```
>>> [[next(i) for j in i if j == 'from'] for i in (iter(x) for x in lst)]
[['B,', 'C', 'D.'], ['D.']]
```

[image: Yo dawg i herd u like comprehension so I put a comprehension in yo comprehension so you comprehend while u not comprehend]